# How to trim string started from substring

Tags: c#, .net, string

How to remove in elegance way second part of string starting from particular substring?
Ex. 
We have string:

```
var someString = "ThisIsSomeString_v1_26102017";
```

as a result we want: `ThisIsSomeString`

I did that:

```
var someString = "ThisIsSomeString_v1_26102017";
var tokens = someString.SplitByLast("_v");
var result = tokens[0];
```

There is any clever way to do that? Some Trim or something?
I mean as a result I want to have first part of string. In this case separator is a "_v" substring. I want to drop everything after "_v" included this "_v".

Comment: Splitting the string is the right way to go about this.

Comment: `IndexOf` to get the location of the substring and then `SubString` to get the part you want.  Also what is `SplitByLast`?  There is not standard method of that name on `string`.

Comment: @GiladGreen the text and code are in sync: code takes the beginning, text asks "hot to remove the end".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`string.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = someString.Substring(0, Math.Max(someString.IndexOf("_v"), 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not any better than the `Substring` implementation, the `Split` might look like this:

```
var result = someString.Split(new[]{"_v"}, StringSplitOptions.None).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this -

```
var result = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf("_v"));
```

It will remove all the text after _v (including _v).

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
var result = input?.Split(new[] { "_v" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

Comment: `var result = input?.Split(new[] { "_v" }, 1)[0];`